What is the difference between mind and consciousness?
I have heard the terms "mind" and "consciousness" used interchangeably, but I am now wondering, is there a difference between them? If so, what is the difference between them? I would like to see some references.

Very little in western psychology; a great deal in traditional eastern. See this this

See The Mind/Brain

"Mind" is not used interchangeably with "consciousness" at least since the end of 19th century (Freud et al.), when the talk of "unconscious mind" became common. Today, even colloquially, consciousness is that aspect of mind which is accessible to introspection. This is reflected in HOT theories:"Higher-order theories of consciousness try to explain the difference between unconscious and conscious mental states in terms of a relation obtaining between the conscious state in question and a higher-order representation of some sort."

The unconcious is part of the mind and not contained inside the concious process.

Many of the answers take an internalist view of the mind. There is an externalist perspective. See https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/content-externalism/.

That would be the unconscious mind and the mindless consciousness. Language is fun.

Mind describes all our internal processes by which we guide a "self" through a complex world.  From the dawn of psychology, it has been clear that our introspection of our consciousness is not the whole story about how our minds work.    Freud inferred three major sub-elements of our minds, only one of which (the ego) is primarily conscious.
Understanding how we do our processing, and why we do what we do, therefore is a broader project than just the study of consciousness.  Consciousness is a particular focus, as it is so apparently unique to living things, so central to what humans seem to be, and is such a challenge to the dominant worldview of physicalism, that understanding and explaining consciousness is a major feature of theories about mind.
For links -- basically the entire field of psychology theory, plus philosophy of mind, is not really linkable.

The key difference is that consciousness is a subset of the effects associated with the mind. Much of your mental activity is subconscious. If, for example, you ever attempt to complete a cryptic crossword, you will find that many of the answers to even quite obscure clues can spring into your mind without you having the slightest awareness of the process through which they arose. The term consciousness is typically used to refer to the mental processes of which we have a direct sort of awareness. The mind is a wider collective term that covers more of our mental activities and capabilities, not just those we experience consciously.

Mind is the substratum within which all thoughts are created. That is, the mind gives rise to thoughts; thoughts are developed within the mind.
Consciousness is the faculty which interacts with these thoughts; that is, consciousness interprets the thoughts of which the mind is creator.

Very important point. This is one of the few aspects of the whole mostly unknown area of mind and consciousness that is up to experimental validation - during meditation it quickly becomes obvious that thoughts and consciousness are not the same, which may or may not be so obvious to many people, before sitting down and experiencing it for themselves.

I can easily lose consciousness, by falling asleep, consuming too much alcohol, or having a general anesthetic; losing my mind would be much more serious.


Mind is the set of all processes in the brain, i.e. mind is a synonym
for the totality of mental processes.

Consciousness is a property of certain mental processes. The search
for the Neural Correlate of Consciousness (NCC) is an active field
of neuroscience. Simple examples of conscious processes are qualia.

All mental processes are located in the brain.



The brain is the physical container or attribution of the mind?

@Howwhye I consider the brain the organ for the mind like the heart is the organ to pump the blood. Both organs are physical objects.

So technically you believe that the mind and body are non-dual.

@Howwhye I do not understand what you mean by "mind and body are non-dual". I consider the living human as a person, and one may focus on the bodily, the mental, the social and on several other aspects of this person.

Consciousness is a state of being.
You are conscious.
Or... you are asleep, in a come, or. Dead and gone.
You don't "have a consciousness".
You are "conscious".
Like if you were running, or nor running... you are conscious, or not conscious.
The "mind" is more personal and more related to who you are.  (When you are conscious that is).
When you are daydreaming, another might ask... "Where's your mind at".  When facing a decision you might get "Have you made your mind up?".
Hope that helps.

Consciousness is the individualized implementation of The Mind in the physical level.

That’s a cool idea but it would be great if you could expand on that a bit with how you came to that conclusion.

@Julius Hamilton, mind ~ menos(μένος) [Greek] / manas [Sanskrit], in conjunction with pneuma(πνεύμα) [Greek] / prana [Sanskrit], produce consciousness as a balancing act of the individual. The whole organism is constantly interfacing with these two forces mainly through the nervous system. The processes that occur in the brain are the epiphenomena of these interractions.

@Julius Hamilton, ... The subject is complex and cannot be easily understood in the Western framework of thinking. You have to study the initial terms, how they were formed in their initial contexts (Greek - Sanskrit), why they have the same etymological roots, how they were paraphrased later on, what is the connection with pneumatology and hence with the main dispute and division between the Eastern and Western churches and finally to experience their meaning throught a (spiritual) framework: meditation, contemplation or any other similar technique.
